# Hide filename, line, and character count when opening Vim

Tags: vim

When I open a file in Vim, the bottom area (below the statusline and to the left of the ruler) displays the current file that's opened, along with line count and character count. How do I disable this from showing on start?

Here is an example of what's displayed and how it's formatted:

[image]

I have already set `laststatus=0`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for `:help 'shortmess'`, specifically the `F` flag:

```
F   don't give the file info when editing a file, like `:silent`
    was used for the command
```